# android float left/right buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Does anybody knows how I can acomplish this in android?

http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/2982/examplehm.png

<, >, +, - are buttons and 0 i 0 are TextView-s.

I just dont get this and have no point how to do this.

Comment: I just need an idea or some tutorial or similar example.. I dont want someone to do this for me

Comment: you could at least try something first,  then ask

Comment: but why u cant give me some point so I can think about it? or tutorial? similar example?

Comment: I cant write some code if I dont know how o think correctly

Comment: How about you start with this one:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: thank u very much I am no retarted, just press on vote down and dont help.. this something more than just simple example, at least I think and I googled so mucch but didnt find similar example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. You don't need to set the orientation manually though, since `LineaLayouts` are set to horizontal orientation by default.

```
<LinearLayout
[...]
>
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/left"
 [...]
 > 

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/plus"
 [...]
 > 

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/txt1"
 [...]
 > 

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/minus"
 [...]

 > 
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/txt2"
 [...]
 > 

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/right"
 [...]
 > 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, I solved. Now I understand when to use vertical and when horizontal orientation.

Comment: Are you sure you want to delve into this?